# Lots of UnsubscriptionError after angular13 migration

Tags: angular

This error is being thrown on console for all the service subscribe which return HTTP observable(api response)

UnsubscriptionErrorImpl {message: "1 errors occurred during unsubscription:\n1) TypeEr…not read properties of undefined (reading 'push')", name: 'UnsubscriptionError', errors: Array(1)}
errors: [TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push') at Subscription. (ht…]
message: "1 errors occurred during unsubscription:\n1) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')"
name: "UnsubscriptionError"
[[Prototype]]: Error

Angular CLI: 13.3.6
Node: 12.22.8
Package Manager: yarn 1.22.11
OS: win32 x64

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/46152

Comment: Please provide relevant code...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.